# dojo 'stopParser' is not working inside template

Tags: javascript, widget, dojo

I have a module/widget that deliberatly calls `stopParser: true` to prevent the dojo parser from parsing its content. This works fine, as long as the widget is directly in an HTML page. As soon as I use the widget inside the template of another widget, `stopParser`does not work anymore. I recon it's a bug, since the same problem exists with `dijit/layout/ContentPane` and the `parserOnLoad`property. Anyone has an explanation or a tip how to solve this?
BR,
Daniel

Comment: Can you post your widget's code?  One thing I immediately notice in `dojo/parser`'s source is that it explicitly checks for `stopParser` on the prototype, not the instance, so depending on what you're doing exactly, that might explain it...

Comment: That is not the problem. I see in `_WidgetsInTemplateMixin`'s code, that it starts the parser with the `template` property always set to `true` instead of using the parameters from the outer parser call. This completely overrides `stopParser`. If I change this to `false` it works, but changing dojo code is not an option for me.